# Asp net core IdentityServer4 GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync returns null

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, two-factor-authentication

I am building an identity server but I can't get the Two Factor Auth to work.  I have a demo project where it works, but somewhere there is a 'magic happens' moment as far as I can see.  The user logs in fine, then hits this code:

```
                //logged in ok, check for mfa
                if (user.TwoFactorEnabled)
                {
                    
                    //make sure it has sms as an option 
                    var providers = await _userManager.GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(user);

                    if (!providers.Contains("Phone"))
```

But the Get valid two factors providers comes back null.  I have a web site where it returns "Phone" and "Email", but I can't figure out where those are specifically set.  In my Startup.cs page I am adding the sms sender like this:

```
services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, SmsSender>();
```

In asp.net identity (not core) I could specifically set them like this:

```
usermanager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("SMS", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<IdentityUser> {MessageFormat = "Code: {0}"});
```

I have tested my Twilio SMS class and it works, sends text just fine.  But how do I register it?  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this very problem when using `AddIdentityCore<TUser>` to get a lightweight
identity registration (without default UI). Calling `AddDefaultTokenProviders`() on the resulting `IIdentityBuilder` populated the collection.

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<MyUserType>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```